# how read a xml file with C# XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, dom, linq-to-xml

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<solidBodies>
  <body>
    <name>BLOCK(1)</name>
    <density>1200</density>
  </body>
  <body>
    <name>BLOCK(8)</name>
    <density>7927,81</density>
  </body>
  <body>
    <name>SPHERE(9)</name>
    <density>7192</density>
  </body>
</solidBodies>
```

Here is my code:

```
private static void ReadSolidBodyPropertyXml(string solidPropertyXmlFilePath)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(solidPropertyXmlFilePath);

    foreach(XElement node in xdoc.Root.Nodes())
    {
        string name = node.Attribute("name").Value;
        int density = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attribute("density").Value);
    }
}
```

Question: I'm trying to get the values ​​of the elements but I get a `NullReferenceException` for `.Value`. What am I doing wrong?

I add my solution:

```
private static void ReadSolidBodyPropertyXml(string solidPropertyXmlFilePath)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(solidPropertyXmlFilePath);

    foreach(XElement node in xdoc.Root.Nodes())
    {
        string name = node.Element("name").Value;
        int density = Convert.ToInt32(node.Element("density").Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `LINQ`

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(XMLFile);

var items = from item in xdoc.Descendants("solidBodies").Elements("body")
            select new
            {
                name = item.Element("name").Value,
                density = item.Element("density").Value
            };

foreach (var item in items)
{
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.name} {item.density}");
}
```

OUTPUT

```
BLOCK(1) 1200
BLOCK(8) 7927,81
SPHERE(9) 7192
```